# vb6 to .NET conversion. i'm stuck

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb6-migration

I have this, and i've been fiddling around with it for a while but i'm completely stuck. can anyone help me make a little sense of this. i'm trying to rewrite this into .NET. thanks.

```
Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 objCmd.ActiveConnection = Application("ConnString")
 With objCmd
  .CommandText = "sp_CheckUserLogin"
  .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  objCmd(1) = strUserName
  Set objRS = .Execute 
 End With
 Set objCmd = Nothing

 If objRS.EOF Then
  strErrString = strErrString & "Invalid Account Information.<br>"
  Call InsertLoginHistory(strUserName, Trim(Request.Form("Password")), Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_HOST"), "User Not Found")
  bLoggedIn = False
 Else
  iUserNumber = objRS("USER_NUMBER")
  strPassword = Trim(objRS("USER_PASSWORD"))
  strIPBand =  Trim(objRS("IP_BAND"))
  iFailedCount =  objRS("FAILED_LOGIN_CNT")
  dLastFailedLogin =  objRS("LAST_FAILED_LOGIN")
  strLoggedInStatus =  objRS("LOGGED_IN_STATUS")
  strLockUser =  objRS("LOCKUSER")
            ....
```

Comment: I'm sure you don't want us to do your work for you. Why don't you show us what you got so we can help you with the specific points you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines should get you going in the right direction.  You will need to 
add a reference for System.Configuration

```
using System.Data.SqlClient
using System.Configuration

SqlConnection sqlConn = null;
SqlCommand sqlCmd = null;
SqlDataReader sqlRdr = null;

try
{
    // get connection string from web.config or app.config
    sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    sqlConn.Open();

    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_CheckUserLogin", sqlConn);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // define parameters like this
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@user", strUserName));
    sqlRdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqlRdr.Read())
    {
        // get values by column name or index
        strPassword = sqlRdr["USER_NUMBER"].ToString();
    }
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // do your error handling here
}
finally
{
    // close connections
     if (sqlConn != null)
        sqlConn.Close();
     if (sqlRdr != null)
        sqlRdr.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're connecting to MS Sql Server, use SqlCommand, SqlConnection and Dataset/DataTable classes. ADO.Net isn't too hard to understand if you know ADO.

Answer (score 0):

`objRS` is a RecordSet. [Here](http://www.timesheetsmts.com/adotutorial.htm) are some tips for VB6 ADO. [Here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson01.aspx) is a tutorial to get you familiar with ADO.NET (the .NET equiv of VB6's ADO).